# go_router. The key [LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#0976b ] was used by multiple widgets

Tags: flutter

When I use `go_router` for navigation containing BottomNavBar, this error happens:

```
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

The key [LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#0976b navbarKey] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were different widgets that both had the following description:
  _BodyBuilder
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2868:13)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:614:13)
#2      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2815:20)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:614:13)
#4      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2811:36)
#5      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:6)
#6      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2935:11)
#7      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3016:8)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:893:19)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
#16     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#17     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

This is where I've created the NavigationKeys and routes:

```
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'rootKey');

//This is the error causing key navbarKey. but it is just used once.
final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(
          debugLabel: 'navbarKey'); //ScaffoldWithBottomNavBar


final goRouter = GoRouter(
      initialLocation: LandingPage.route,
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      debugLogDiagnostics: true,
      routes: [
        ShellRoute(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return ScaffoldWithBottomNavBar(tabs: tabs, child: child);
          },
          routes: [
            //home
            GoRoute(
              path: '/home',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: const LandingPage(),
              ),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path:'home/d',
                  builder: (context, state) => const DetailsPage(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            //categories
            GoRoute(
              path: '/categories',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: const CategoriesPage(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          path: LoginPage.route,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const LoginPage(child: LoginForm()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hi. Did you find the solution? I found out that the problem comes from navigatorKey in ShellRoute.

Comment: Yes@amin. After upgrading the package the problem solved